# templates inside application in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project.
I am getting   `TemplateDoesNotExist` error in my browser window. I think django unable to find templates inside application in django project. I am unable to figure it out what is wrong in my code.

project structure is something like that -

```
schoolproject
    |
    |______ course
    |                 
    |______ fees 
    |
    |______ schoolproject
    |
    |______ manage.py
```

course application folder -

```
course
   |
   |___ templates
   |       |
   |       |____ allcourse.html
   |       |
   |       |____ course.html
   |        
   |___ admin.py
   |
   |___ apps.py
   |
   |___ models.py
   |
   |___ tests.py
   |
   |___ urls.py
   |
   |___ views.py
```

schoolproject/course/views.py

```
def course(request):
    return render(request, 'allcourse.html')

def course_python(request):
    return render(request, 'course.html')
```

schoolproject/course/urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.course),
    path('course-python/', views.course_python)
]
```

schoolproject/schoolproject/urls.py

```
import course
import fees

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('course/', include('course.urls')),
    path('fees/', include('fees.urls')),
]
```

On hitting :-  127.0.0.1:8000/course/

[image]

And on hitting:-  127.0.0.1:8000/course/course-python/

[image]

In settings.py -

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...  
    },
]
```

Comment: Check if you have set `APP_DIRS` to `True` in settings.py

Comment: Might it can help: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/template-structure

Comment: Yes, `APP_DIRS` is `True`  in settings.py

Comment: Hello @AmanGhanghoriya It should be in this format *`yourapp/templates/yourapp/your_page.html`* so it will look like this ***`course/templates/course/allcourse.html`***

Comment: Ankit Tiwari, even this correction, giving same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update your folders as

```
schoolproject
    |
    |______ course
                  |______ templates
# In templates create a new folder called course
                                   |______ course
    |                 
    |______ fees 
    |
    |______ schoolproject
    |
    |______ manage.py
```

- Do this for all apps

## In schoolproject/course/views.py

```
def course(request):
    return render(request, 'course/allcourse.html')

def course_python(request):
    return render(request, 'course/course.html')
```

## In settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...  
    },
]
```

Comment: If it didn't work then comment your error again